# Why are my ggplots stretched out?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I am using to generate a plot

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=foo1,aes(x=lon,y=lat,shape=id))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Climate Classes",values=cols)+
  ggtitle("Distribution of Flash Flood Events in CONUS")+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.5)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.24),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))+
  ggsave("useventsmap_bw.png")
```

Till yesterday, the same code was giving me a well-formatted figure

[image]
But now it the figure is looking very weird. I haven't changed the code at all (Just made a slight change in the original data which shouldn't affect the proportions of the figure). I am working in RStudio in a Windows machine. Is this a common problem? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Why not specify `height` and `width` in your `ggsave` call?

Comment: I always did it this way to keep it simple and it chose the best ratio. The figures looked perfect. :( I'll try to use Width/Height ratio directly.

Comment: And, I know you asked a question about aspect ratio before, but you really really should use `coord_map()` instead of using `coord_fixed()`. Choosing a coord fixed ratio of 1.5 because it "looks right" is just giving you a warped Mercator projection.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I am having this recurring problem. I used coord_map(), but it is not changing the figure. Will try again. Generally, I just restart PC and it solves the problem. Probably the most unscientific way of fixing it...

Comment: Nope, coord_map(projection = "mercator") doesn't fix it.

Comment: Ok, assigning Width, Height fixes it. I wish I had something automatic though.

Comment: `coord_map(projection = "mercator")` won't fix any problem you've identified. But the rest of us, we see a weird looking map, and it will solve that problem. Or, you could do something even nicer like `coord_map(projection = "azequalarea")`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out now. You are right.